# Please update your includePath

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I'm in a school course that uses C++. With the code they give us, we have stuff in the headers like:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include "cs221util/PNG.h"
#include "cs221util/HSLAPixel.h"
```

I get the errors

```
{
    "resource": "/home/k/xxx/cs221/lab_debug/sketchify.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "code": "1696",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (/home/k/xxx/cs221/lab_debug/sketchify.cpp).",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 4,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 4,
    "endColumn": 27
}
```

and

```
{
    "resource": "/home/k/xxx/cs221/lab_debug/sketchify.cpp",
    "owner": "C/C++",
    "code": "1696",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "cannot open source file \"iostream\"",
    "source": "C/C++",
    "startLineNumber": 3,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 3,
    "endColumn": 20
}
```

even though all everything compiles and runs fine. I was looking online and perhaps a solution is modifying c_cpp_properties.json? I opened that and have no idea what anything in that file means. What am I supposed to do? What does everything mean?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp